# Independence of points on Elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $P_1(x_1,y_1),P_2(x_2,y_2)...P_n(x_n,y_n)$ be $n$ rational points on given Elliptic curve. How do we prove they are independent? Are there any theorems/results/algorithms/softwares to prove their independence?

Comment: In general, this is a difficult problem. I think that they are $\Bbb Z$-linearly independent iff the determinant of the matrix $(\langle P_i, P_j \rangle)_{i,j}$ is not zero, where $\langle -,- \rangle$ is the Néron-Tate height pairing.

Comment: @Watson The application of this result is exactly what I found in one of the papers. But, I am not able to find resources/references for this result?

Comment: See §2.7 in Lozano-Robledo _Elliptic curves, modular forms, and their L-functions_, or prop. 4.10 [here](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid:c2557d3d-9fa0-4053-8f22-b1caff306c25) (click on "view" on the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already somewhat been answered in the comments but I'd like to add a little example of a Sage session playing with this.

The point is that the canonical height pairing is a symmetric bilinear map
$$
E(\mathbf Q ) \times E(\mathbf Q) \to \mathbf R
$$
so if there is a linear relationship between some points, there should be the same relationship between all of their heights.

You should be able to do all of this in a Sage session (Sage is free!) (there was a bug with the rational_points command in some recent versions of sage so that might not work depending on your version)

Let's start with a not-so-randomly-chosen elliptic curve (I picked this one to have rank 4 so that this would be interesting, see http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?rank=4)

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([1, -1, 0, -79, 289])
sage: E.rational_points(bound=10)
[(-10 : 3 : 1),
 (-10 : 7 : 1),
 (-9 : -10 : 1),
 (0 : 1 : 0),
 (3 : -10 : 1),
 (3 : 7 : 1),
 (4 : -7 : 1),
 (4 : 3 : 1),
 (5 : -3 : 1),
 (5 : -2 : 1),
 (6 : -5 : 1),
 (6 : -1 : 1),
 (7 : -10 : 1),
 (7 : 3 : 1),
 (8 : 7 : 1)]
sage: L = E.rational_points(bound=10)
```

`L` is the list of a whole bunch of points we found now

We take the pairing matrix of the first two points, looks rank 1 so determinant 0!

```
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[0:2])
[ 2.38682061714418 -2.38682061714418]
[-2.38682061714418  2.38682061714418]
```

and it is! we should expect this though, points 0 and 1 have the same x-coord so are inverses of each other

```
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[0:2]).determinant()
0.000000000000000
```

what about points 1,2?

```
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[1:3])
[ 2.38682061714418 0.126691370405363]
[0.126691370405363  2.68947630168514]
```

doesn't look rank $\lt 2$ at all! though it is always symmetric

Similar for points 7,8

```
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[7:9])
[ 1.17647633591898 0.167621062889770]
[0.167621062889770  1.20262600414243]
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[7:9]).determinant()
1.38676421411007
```

We can try 3 other points now

```
sage: L[5:10:2]
[(3 : 7 : 1), (4 : 3 : 1), (5 : -2 : 1)]
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[5:10:2]).determinant()
1.30015022478383
```

this is clearly non-zero so assuming correctness of the software these three points are independent.

What about non-independence, in general it is notoriously hard to prove real numbers *are* zero on a computer, leading to problems when trying to prove dependence in general. With rational points of elliptic curves though we are fundamentally in a finitely generated abelian group though, so we can do more

Here are 4 points, which don't have an obvious relationship by glancing at!

```
sage: L[4:12:2]
[(3 : -10 : 1), (4 : -7 : 1), (5 : -3 : 1), (6 : -5 : 1)]
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[4:12:2])
[  1.72683492334016 -0.959801459379726  0.222652978555837  0.767033463960439]
[-0.959801459379726   1.17647633591898 -0.167621062889770  0.216674876539249]
[ 0.222652978555837 -0.167621062889770   1.20262600414243 0.0550319156660674]
[ 0.767033463960439  0.216674876539249 0.0550319156660674  0.983708340499687]
```

Looks like the determinant is zero:

```
sage: E.height_pairing_matrix(L[4:12:2]).det()
-2.66453525910038e-15
```

So are they dependent? Lets give the matrix we think has some kernel a name.

```
sage: M = E.height_pairing_matrix(L[4:12:2])
```

Sage will complain if you ask it for the kernel as we are over the reals to some finite precision, so we use a little trick:

```
sage: M.change_ring(QQ).eigenvectors_right()
[(1.833143676963028?e-16,
  [(1, 1.000000000000000?, 1.?e-16, -1.000000000000000?)],
  1),
 (1.135131138616548?,
  [(1, -2.478168820884934?, -8.24803196664211?, -1.478168820884934?)],
  1),
 (1.289199998123811?,
  [(1, 3.978262464606312?, -1.966228843927413?, 4.978262464606312?)],
  1),
 (2.665314467160902?,
  [(1, -0.615399695397310?, 0.2372153947344239?, 0.3846003046026902?)],
  1)]
```

So it looks like $(1,1,0,-1)$ is a kernel vector (i.e. $L[4] + L[6] = L[10]$)

```
sage: M*matrix([[1],[1],[0],[-1]])
[    0.000000000000000]
[ 5.55111512312578e-17]
[-5.55111512312578e-17]
[-1.11022302462516e-16]
sage: L[4] + L[6] - L[10]
(0 : 1 : 0)
```

indeed this is a relation.

Comment: That is very helpful . Thanks for your time!