# Sage code to check independence of rational points on elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, sagemath

Suppose I have three rational points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ on certain elliptic curve. Then they are linearly independent if and only if the determinant of matrix $(<P_i,P_j>)_{i,j}$ is non zero where $<\_,\_ >$ is Neron-Tate height pairing.

How to write a code in Sage or Pari to compute this determinant. Note that I don't want to write an equation of my elliptic curve in the code to compute rational points first. Rather I know my rational points and want to directly put rational points and compute the determinant.

Comment: If you do not provide the equation of the curve, how do you compare its Neron-Tate height? Given three points on the plane, you can always write down an elliptic curve which passes through all three which make the points dependent.

Comment: @Hw Chu Yes. Mistake! So in general, how do we write a code in Sage to find that determinant. Can you please illustrate me though some example.

Comment: Try asking this question in the coding branch of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SageMath this can be accomplished using the command `height_pairing_matrix`. For example:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 + x*y = x^3 + 1 over Rational Field
sage: pts = E.gens()
sage: pts
[(-1 : 1 : 1), (0 : -1 : 1)]
sage: M = E.height_pairing_matrix(points = pts)
sage: M
[0.541484699372469 0.161800998136433]
[0.161800998136433 0.463307138146013]
sage: M.det()
0.224694163418167
```

You can find more information, including many examples, in [the documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_number_field.html).

Comment: 3000, So using above code, sage will first generate these rational points, right? What If I already know my rational points, I don't want Sage to generate the points because it would take my time. How should I write a code in that case?

Comment: If you already have a list of the points, you can input it as `points = ` in the `height_pairing_matrix` function. I tried to show this in my example; I could've just put `E.height_pairing_matrix()` and it would've computed the generators automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a sage expert. But I know you can call pari within sage and here you can compute the Gram/height matrix from the points and determine its determinant. Suppose you `e` is your elliptic curve (in pari this created by `ellinit`) and suppose `P1,P2,P3` are your points then you just use the following commands:

```
v=[P1,P2,P3];
m = ellheightmatrix(e,v);
print(matdet(m));
```

If the last line is $0$ then your points are dependent. Either something similar is done in sage or just call pari commands from sage.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar was already asked at [Independence of points on Elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021423/independence-of-points-on-elliptic-curve) the answers there are the same as above but maybe a little more extensive.

Edit: I just noticed the question asker is the same as the previous question. So maybe this question really is trying to ask something different. The height of a point will depend on the elliptic curve itself so you will need to put the equation of the curve somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I was actually expecting you to comment as I had worked with your answer you provided me last time. You are right my question is different from the last one. I wanted to feed Sage only may rational points even including the equation of elliptic curve. But I don't want sage to compute the rational points. I already have a rational points in my hand and I want to compute determinant for my specific rational points.

Comment: If you give sage the equation of and elliptical curve it will not compute any rational points by default. You can write `P = E((1,0))` to define a point with coordinates (1,0) on E if you know it. Then a list of such can be given to height_pairing_matrix . you will have go define the elliptic curve though as the matrix depends on the equation of the curve.

Comment: Thanks for more clarification.