# Show the following points are independent on elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-82x$ using Sage.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, sagemath

How to show that the following points are independent on elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-82x$ using Sage or any other software.

There is some determinant of certain matrix which I need to compute constructed from Néron-Tate height pairing. If this determinant is non-zero, then the points are independent.  How to write a code to find this determinant? Three points on above curve are:

$[(-8,12),(-1,9),(49/4,231/8)]$

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not suitable for this site, although it's related to mathematics.

Comment: I saw it in the papers of Elliptic curves. I am sure those  work on elliptic curves use Sage and that makes it relevant to this website.

Comment: I think you can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081066/sage-code-to-check-independence-of-rational-points-on-elliptic-curve)

Try the code below [here.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

E = EllipticCurve([-82,0]);
pts = [E(-8,12),E(-1,9),E(49/4,231/8)];
M = E.height_pairing_matrix(points = pts);
print(M);
print(M.det());

Comment: In particular the determinant is large so they are independent. If it's very small but not zero it's taken to be likely dependent from my understanding (This is from "Elliptic Curves, Modular Forms and their L-functions", page 48). Probably the methods cannot guarantee computing a zero determinant?

Comment: @WhatsUp Questions about using CASes are expressly on-topic (except for those about Mathematica, which has a dedicated SE site). https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @TravisWillse I see, I thought it would be more suitable for sage's own forum.

Comment: @WhatsUp SAGE's elliptic curve support is one of its (relative and absolute) strengths. I would be surprised if this question weren't already effectively answered there (or possibly even in the documentation).

Comment: @YongHaoNg Thank you very much. It works.